# How does one extract info from the 'More Info' of finder?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript, finder

I have been trying to extract keywords from the 'More Info' section of finder. I have been able to extract data from the 'General' section, but have not been able to find a method to extract it from the 'More Info' section. Below is some of the code I have for the 'General' section

-- CODE VERSION 1 --

```
on run
tell application "Finder"
    set selectedItem to (item 1 of (get selection))
    set infoList to {}
    copy ("Displayed Name: " & displayed name of selectedItem) to end of infoList
    copy ("Kind: " & kind of selectedItem) to end of infoList
    copy ("Size: " & size of selectedItem & " (" & physical size of selectedItem & ")") to end of infoList
    copy ("Where: " & (selectedItem as alias) as string) to end of infoList
    copy ("Created: " & creation date of selectedItem) to end of infoList
    copy ("Modified: " & modification date of selectedItem) to end of infoList
    copy ("Name & Extension: " & name of selectedItem) to end of infoList
    copy ("Locked: " & locked of selectedItem) to end of infoList
    copy ("Comments: " & comment of selectedItem) to end of infoList
    copy ("Owner: " & owner of selectedItem) to end of infoList
    copy ("Group: " & group of selectedItem) to end of infoList
end tell
set {od, AppleScript's text item delimiters} to {AppleScript's text item delimiters, return}
set infoAsString to infoList as string
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to od
set the clipboard to infoAsString
return infoAsString
end run
```

-- CODE VERSION 2 --

```
    tell application "Image Events"
        -- start the Image Events application
        launch
        -- open the image file
        set this_image to open (inputPath & "HighRes/" & fname & ".tif")
        -- extract the value for the metadata tag
        tell this_image
            set the imgDescp to the value of metadata tag "description"
        end tell
        -- purge the open image data
        close this_image
    end tell
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find most, if not all, of that in the Spotlight metadata store, for example:

```
do shell script “mdls “ & quoted form of “/posix/path/to/file”
```

The individual items can be extracted by specifying the attribute name - see the [mdls man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/mdls/).

Comment: do shell script "mdls -name kMDItemKeywords " & quoted form of 'Path'